# Как сохранить информацию о выбранных местах в бд через php?

Tags: php, html, jquery, mysql

Есть схема кинозала. Выбор мест работает через Jquery. Как сохранить информацию о выбранных местах в mysql (через php)?

Вот код:
https://codepen.io/Bymbob/pen/OJENXpg

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="design.css" />
  <title>Movie Seat Booking</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="movie-container">
    <label> Выбранный фильм </label>
    <select id="movie">
      <option>Фильм 1</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <ul class="showcase">
    <li>
      <div class="seat"></div>
      <small>Н/В</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat selected"></div>
      <small>Выбрано</small>
    </li>
    <li>
      <div class="seat occupied"></div>
      <small>Занято</small>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="screen"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat"> A5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">B5</div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C1</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C2</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C3</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C4</div>
      <div class="col col-lg-1 place mx-auto unbooked seat">C5</div>
    </div>

  </div>
  <p class="text">Вы выбрали <span id="count">0</span> мест
  </p>
  <div class="container order d-grid gap-2 mx-auto">
    <input class="btn btn-secondary mx-auto" type="button" value="Забронировать" id="submit">
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>


    $(function () {
  $(".place").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
  });
  $(".unbooked").attr("title","Unbooked");
  $(".taken").attr("title","Taken");
});

$("#submit").click(function () {
  $(".place").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).addClass("taken");
      $(this).removeClass("unbooked");
      $(this).attr("title","Taken");
      $(this).addClass("occupied");
    }
  });
});

const container = document.querySelector('.container')
const seats = document.querySelectorAll('.row .seat:not(.occupied)')
const count = document.getElementById('count')

container.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
  console.log(e.target)
  if (
    e.target.classList.contains('seat') &&
    !e.target.classList.contains('occupied')
  ) {
    console.log(e.target)
    e.target.classList.toggle('selected')
    updateSelectedCount()
  }
})
```

Comment: `Как сохранить информацию о выбранных местах в mysql (через php)?` - а как это, в принципе, работает, вы знаете или нет? Сохранение в базу имел ввиду.

Comment: Да, неправильно выразился.

Comment: Собираете на js данные, отправляете их ajax'ом на php скрипт который записывает их в базу

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, показать на моём примере? Чтобы я на нём разобрался.

Comment: Добавил как собрать и сохранить. Как потом извлечь и восстановить состояние, разберётесь сами или тоже помочь? Там просто с базы получаем уже строку, её парсим JSON.parse(str), получаем массив. По нему пробегаемся и по каждому ряду и его местам добавляем классы, в зависимости от тех параметров что сохранены

Comment: Да, помогите, пожалуйста. Большое спасибо за предыдущий ответ!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function save() {
  let dataArr = [];
  // проходимся во всем .row что внутри .container, то есть, по рядам
  [...document.querySelectorAll('.container .row')].forEach((row, idx) => {
    let seats = row.querySelectorAll('.seat'), 
        seatsData = []; 
    // для каждого ряда проходимся по местам (row.querySelectorAll('.seat'))
    [...seats].forEach(seat => {
      // собираем в массив информацию о каждом месте текущего ряда
      // зеленый, занято, selected - проверяем наличие класса
      // серый, забронировано, occupied- проверяем наличие класса
      seatsData.push({
        name: seat.innerText.trim(),
        selected: seat.classList.contains('selected'),
        occupied: seat.classList.contains('occupied'),
      });
    });
    // записываем в итоговый массив информацию по каждому ряду:
    // его индекс
    // информацию о его местах
    dataArr.push({
      rowIndex: idx,
      seats: seatsData
    });
  });
  console.log('stored data', dataArr);
  // ajax post запрос
  // store.php - файл что записывает в БД данные
  $.post("store.php", {data: dataArr});
}
```

Теперь функцию save() вызывать надо в момент, когда нужно "сохранение", то есть, запись в БД.

Можно в БД хранить эти данные как json-строку
Тогда приблизительное содержимое файла store.php будет выглядеть так:

```
if ( !empty($_POST['data']) ) {
  $data = json_encode($_POST['data']); // это теперь строка

  // тут запись в Базу Данных
}
```